# Submit a PySpark job to a cluster with the '--py-files' argument

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I was trying to submit a job with the the GCS uri of the zip of the python files to use (via the --py-files argument) and the python file name as the PY_FILE argument value.
This did not seem to work. Do I need to provide some relative path for the PY_FILE value? The PY_FILE is also included in the zip.
e.g. in

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark  --cluster clustername --py-files gcsuriofzip PY_FILE
```

what should the value of PY_FILE be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good question. To answer this question, I am going to use the [PySpark wordcount example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py).

In this case, I created two files, one called `test.py` which is the file I want to execute and another called `wordcount.py.zip` which is a zip containing a **modified** `wordcount.py` file designed to mimic a module I want to call.

My `test.py` file looks like this:

```
import wordcount
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wordcount.wctest(sys.argv[1])
```

I modified the `wordcount.py` file to eliminate the main method and to add a named method:

```
...
from pyspark import SparkContext

...
def wctest(path):
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonWordCount")
...
```

I can call the whole thing on [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) by using the following `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark  --cluster <cluster-name> \
--py-files gs://<bucket>/wordcount.py.zip gs://<bucket>/test.py \ 
gs://<bucket>/input/input.txt
```

In this example `<bucket>` is the name (or path) to my bucket and `<cluster-name>` is the name of my Dataproc cluster.